# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'value1' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    value1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    value2 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    value3 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    proposedAnswer : Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.state.value1 + this.state.value2 + this.state.value3,
    numQuestions : 0,
    numCorrect : 0
  };
}
```

I don't understand how it cannot read the value of the variable 'value1'.

Comment: The state is empty at the very beginning, so you can't reference it that way. Try to extract value 1,2,3 as variables and use the variable instead of `this.state`

Comment: Its still not defined to be used

Comment: You are using variable inside it's declaration, that's why it's undefined

Comment: you accessed state.value1 before the assignment ends

Answer (score 3):

The state is still empty when you want to use it.
When you call `this.state.value1`, it won't refer to the current object but to the `state` itself, which hasn't been set yet because you're defining it.

You could extract the values as local variables and use them instead.

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  const val1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  const val2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  const val3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  this.state = {
    value1 : val1,
    value2 : val2,
    value3 : val3,
    proposedAnswer : Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + val1 + val2 + val3,
    numQuestions : 0,
    numCorrect : 0
  };
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ABGR they are random values